# Plot Meijer G function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

How to plot using Mathematica the Meijer G function

$$
G^{m l}_{p q} \left(\omega t \  \Bigg\vert \  {a_1,\cdots,a_p\atop b_1,\cdots,b_q} \right)
$$

Thanks

Comment: The Meijer G function is built in to *Mathematica*: see the [documentation for MeijerG](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give the parameters numeric values.

```
Plot[{
  MeijerG[
   {{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {}},
    {{0}, {-(3/2), -(3/2)}}, 
       x], 
  8*MeijerG[{{}, {2}}, 
        {{1/2, 3/2}, {}}, 
    x]}, 
   {x, -1, 5},
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed["Expressions", Bottom]]
```

[image]